# ASP.NET Web App to compare performance on different hardware?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hardware, web-applications, benchmarking

I'm looking for an open source C# ASP.NET Web App that can be loaded onto 2 or more dedicated servers and provide me with metrics on how that server is performing. E.g. Click on a page and the app does a number of in-memory iterations and/or calculations to test processor throughput. Another page would do a bunch of disk access and report on that.

I could put one together myself but there might already be something out there with a whole ton of tools in it to do this. I would imagine that I'm not the first one that would want to compare two machines for use as a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't what you're asking for exactly but Microsoft has a tool that might get you what you want in a different way.  It's called the [Web Capacity Analysis Tool](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6).

The idea would be to test your website on two different servers with this tool and see how it does.

Comment: +1 Thanks Steve - that's a useful tool I didn't know about that can be used on the client side to load test each of the servers but I would still need the web site/app to be running to load test.